# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query is working fine in Sql Server Management Studio, But when I try it to run in a dataset & pass Date(@Param2 & @Pram3) from datetime picker, its throwing an exception Conversion failed. I don't know whats wrong with that, my other queries are working fine.Is this happening because of UNION ALL?

**.NET Code**

```
startDatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
endDatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
DataTable ntwTable = ntw.GetData(owner,start,end);
start = startDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
end = endDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT        o.Name, SUM(sq.SQuantity * sq.SRate) AS TotalSale, SUM(sq.PrQuantity * sq.PrRate) AS TotalPurchase, (SUM(sq.PQuantity) - SUM(sq.SQuantity)) 
                                 * (SUM(sq.PQuantity * sq.PRate) / SUM(sq.PQuantity)) AS Inventory
        FROM            (SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, RatePerShare AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, 0 AS PrQuantity, 0 AS PrRate, Date
                                  FROM            Purchase
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, 0 AS PQuantity, 0 AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, Quantity AS PrQuantity, RatePerShare AS PrRate, Date
                                  FROM            Purchase AS pr
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, 0 AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, 0 AS PrQuantity, 0 AS PrRate, Date
                                  FROM            Bonus
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, CostOfShare AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, 0 AS PrQuantity, 0 AS PrRate, Date
                                  FROM            RightShare
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, 0 AS PQuantity, 0 AS PRate, Quantity AS SQuantity, RatePerShare AS SRate, 0 AS PrQuantity, 0 AS PrRate, Date
                                  FROM            Sales) AS sq INNER JOIN
                                 Owner AS o ON o.OwnerId = sq.OwnerId
        WHERE        (o.OwnerId = @Param1) AND (sq.Date BETWEEN @Param2 AND @Param3)
        GROUP BY sq.CompanyId, o.Name
```

Comment: What are `@Param2` and `@Param3`'s data types?  How are you calling the query in your code?

Comment: You haven't shown the calling code. But it's almost certainly because (at some point) you cause a needless conversion of a `datetime` value to a string. And then things go wrong with conversion back to a `datetime` value

Comment: Can we see the code where you are passing it in.... if it works in SSMS and not in C# its likely an issue with passing it in.

Comment: the datea type of Param2 & Param3 string, where as in database Date is store as date format

Comment: kindly have a look, i've edited the question

Comment: Although you've not shown complete code, yes, it's as I guessed - you're calling functions to convert the datetime into a string. **STOP DOING THAT**. Pass the datetime values as parameters, and they'll remain as datetime values throughout.

Comment: c# have automatically converted the datatype of date to string. When I imported it from management studio

Comment: @Damien, surpised you got 3 up votes for yelling at the person asking a question... STOP YELLING!

Comment: @user2516394 - is the SQL inside of a stored procedure? And if so, are the parameters declared inappropriately? If not, I'm not sure in what circumstance the parameters would be inappropriately converted

Comment: @logixologist - I said that the problem was likely because they were converting values to strings. They've not shown all of the code yet, but somehow them adding the code that calls `ToShortDateString` was meant to - what - make me try to not emphasize to them that they're doing something wrong?

Comment: I hear you man. ALL CAPS is a universally known thing for YELLING and when you bold face it (which I still cant figure out how to do in a comment :)), it almost sounded like a scolding as opposed to being constructive teaching.

Comment: @logixologist http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there are two (obvious) possibilities for a failure.

The first would be in implicit conversion error in the `date` column.  This would occur if `purchase.date` were a date/time value, but one of columns in the `union all` is not:  `bonus.date`, rightshares.date`, or`sales.date`.  To be honest, I would be surprised if this is the case.  However, it is easy enough to check for.  Just run the`union all` query in SSMS to see if an error occurs.

The second possibility is something wrong with `@Param1` or `@Param2`.  These seem to be passed as strings.  You can test this by looking at the string and just doing:

```
select cast(@Param1 as datetime), cast(@Parame2 as datetime)
```

One possible problem is different date formats at the operating system and database levels.  In one, for instance, 20/01/2013 might be Jan 20th and in another an error.  If this is the problem, you can use `convert()` to convert the parameters to the right format (in the database) or convert them before passing them.

Comment: (CONVERT(CHAR(10), sq.Date, 111) BETWEEN @Param2 AND @Param3)
thanks alot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't the best answer, however, it appears this is due to regional settings. If you change the following two lines:

```
start = startDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
end = endDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

To:

```
start = startDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
end = endDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Then I believe this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

(CONVERT(CHAR(10), sq.Date, 111) BETWEEN @Param2 AND @Param3)

Just need to convert.